# Uploaded Image Disappeard When Heroku Server Restart

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am using node.js to upload files to my Heroku server. Everything works fine, but when the Heroku server restarts or goes down all the uploaded files disappears, the URL hits returns 'Not Found'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experienced this months ago.  You need to host the images somewhere else as Heroku does not support storing files in them.  Ended up using Cloudinary to store files, and then later on getting a VPS server.

Answer (score 1):

Media files and other user content that is uploaded by users should not be stored on Heroku. Heroku was built to run the application code and it only cares about the files of your application that are in your repository.

Heroku discards your previous environment on every deploy, and launches a new one based on your code repository.

So only application code should stay there, other things should be delegated to other services, in this case for file storage you should use something like S3 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has something called [Ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

From the documentation:

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the
>   most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running
>   processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no
>   files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and
>   **any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or
>   restarted**.