# Heroku images are gone in new pushes

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mongoose, gitignore

Need your Help!
I deployed my nodejs app (only backend) to heroku and it includes a part where the user must insert documents in format jpg, jpeg, png! All pictures are located in the static folder (/assets/docs)! before pushing the changed code, I tried to create users and their pictures are shown! but when I do a new push to heroku, old files are gone and not showing!
I tried to ignore that static folder in new pushes - /assets/docs/* useless, /assets - useless, /assets/docs - useless
But as an experiment, I put 1 .jpg file in that static folder and pushed it. it always stays even in new pushes (with ignores also)
Using multer and mongoose

file uploading with multer

```
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'assets/docs/',
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const up = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024
    },
    fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|docx|doc|pdf)$/)) {
            return cb (Error("Allowed file types are png jpg jpeg docx doc pdf"), false)
        }

        cb (null, true)
    }
})
```

saving files - mongoose

```
router.post('/register-employee', uploadDocument.single('passport'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const emp = await new Employee({
            ...req.body,
            passport: `docs/${req.file.filename}`
        })

        await emp.save()

        res.json(emp)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({errorMessage: e.message})
    }
})
```

gitignore file

```
/node_modules
/.vscode
/.idea
/config
/assets/docs
```

setting up a public folder

```
const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, '../assets')
app.use(express.static(publicDir))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploaded Image Disappeard When Heroku Server Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178758/uploaded-image-disappeard-when-heroku-server-restart)

Answer (score 1):

The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted.

Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

You can get over this issue by using an external file storage system like Amazon s3 to persist data across restarts on a dyno.

You can read more here: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: but i added static image named 123.jpg in assets/doc folder! and it always stays there

Comment: That's because that was part of the build process. Any data added after the instance has started will be discarded once the instance is stopped or restarted.